# Java record audio only when someone is speaking

Tags: java, voice-recognition

I'm building a voice assistant. I have a working audio recorder that I can stop and start easily.

I just want to be able to detect when the user is actually speaking (it isn't silent) so that I only record what they say, stopping the recording when they stop speaking.

I've been struggling to find a way of doing this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit:
So far I've only found Sphinx4 to be able to detect a voice input but it's been flaky at best and I haven't been able to use it to trigger my sound recorder.

Comment: I'm building a voice assistant for a college project, so voice detection is kind of important! I've tried for days... I'll edit it to show what I've done already.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar project and am using Sphinx4. As the OP said, using Sphinx4 to detect when a user is speaking (and just as importantly when they **stop** speaking) was an issue. As they said, it was "flaky" at best. Fortunately, I came up with a solution that hopefully helps others that stumble along here.

There are two solid ways I found that worked with Sphinx:

**1st Solution:** Get the Sphinx4 source and copy the classes from package `edu.cmu.sphinx.api` into your project. There were about 9 files in there, starting with `AbstractSpeechRecognizer` and ending in `StreamSpeakRecognizer`. Since the OP is talking about voice recognition, it is assumed that their `inputstream` is from a microphone, which makes the `LiveSpeechRecognizer` and `Microphone` classes important. Change the imports in your main java activity and import that package (or individual classes as necessary).

From there, there are multiple options. I ended up writing a method in `LiveSpeechRecognizer` and `Microphone` that used the results from `[LiveSpeechRecognizer].getResult()` and putting a shared boolean in there to recognize when a voice is detected. `LiveSpeechRecognizer` returns results whenever someone finishes speaking, so basically you just set the boolean when the first audio is detected, and detect the voice after the next results come in. Add a timer (I used java's `Executor`) in a separate thread to detect how long since the last words were detected (i.e. 2 seconds). This way if something goes wrong with the mic or they say a really short sentence, it'll still detect the "end".

In this solution, extending `sphinx.api` isn't strictly necessary, however I found the results a lot faster when modifying `Microphone` directly instead of waiting for the results from the main activity.

**2nd Solution:** You could also modify the source for Sphinx4 so that when "noise" is detected below a certain level it means the user has stopped talking. Sphinx is continuously monitoring the microphone using Java's `TargetDataLine`. Mess around with the threshold in which it filter's out noise and implement a listener when it changes too much. This approach is absolutely awful for voice recognition, but the OP wanted to detect when a person starts and stops talking, which this will do.